# passing variables between python 3 scripts using subprocess command ('import * from ...' command just works on module level)

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, subprocess

i have a python 3 script('script1') on windows, and i try to pass a variable('var') to another script('script2').

script1:

```
import subprocess
from tkinter import *
w=Tk()
def script2(var):
    subprocess.Popen('script2.py',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
b1=Button(w,text='var 1',command=lambda:script2('var 1'))
b1.pack()
b2=Button(w,text='var 2',command=lambda:script2('var 2'))
b2.pack()
w.mainloop()
```

script2:

```
print(var)
```

nothing happens...thx all

Comment: When using a subprocess, this is only possible by using command line arguments, would that be an option for you?

Comment: do see the UI with buttons?

Comment: What is your platform? `subprocess.Popen('script2.py',...)` does not work in Windows.  It should be `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'script2.py'], ...)`.  However using `subprocess` to run a Python script, the script will be executed as a new process and so it cannot access any variable in current process.  You need to pass it using command line argument and use `sys.argv` to access it inside `script2.py`.

Comment: @NumanIjaz yes i do

Comment: @acw1668 have u got a doc link please?

Comment: It is easy to search on internet.  For example, search `python sys.argv` and you will find examples on using `sys.argv`.